# Python: zip nested array

Tags: python, zip, tensor

I have the following tensor:

```
mytensor = tensor([[0.6193, 0.6647, 0.4719, 0.5521, 0.5549, 0.4047],
        [0.5618, 0.5821, 0.4368, 0.5164, 0.5080, 0.3930],
        [0.5705, 0.5892, 0.4449, 0.5204, 0.5105, 0.4008]])
```

and a list:

```
mylist = ('buy', 'book', 'test', 'sell', 'watch', 'sell')
```

The result I want to achieve:

```
[[('buy', 0.6193), ('book', 0.6647), ('test', 0.4719), ('sell', 0.5521), ('watch', 0.5549), ('sell', 0.4047)],
 [('buy', 0.5618), ('book', 0.5821), ('test', 0.4368), ('sell', 0.5164), ('watch', 0.5080), ('sell', 0.3930)],
 [('buy', 0.5705), ('book', 0.5892), ('test', 0.4449), ('sell', 0.5204), ('watch', 0.5105), ('sell', 0.4008)]]
```

My first approach was to do a loop:

```
newList= []
for values in mytensor:
   newList.append(list(zip(mylist, values)))
```

And it works, but I was wondering if there is a better and more performant way?

Comment: "Better" along what metric?

Comment: Performance, it feels slow to loop through each of the value of the tensor since I have to perform the same operation on all of the values. But I might be wrong

Comment: The whole *point* of a loop is to do "the same operation" multiple times, presumably on/with different data each time.  And if by "better" you mean "more performant", why repeat yourself?

Comment: Fair enough, I was hoping to find a way like matrix operations work, where you can do things in parallel but still keeping the order, rather than using a sequential loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more concise:

```
[list(zip(mylist, embedding)) for embedding in mytensor]
```